# Proving that the improper integral is divergent. $\int_0 ^2 x^2 \ln x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

The task is "Evaluate the following improper integral or prove that it
diverges" 
$$
\int_0 ^2 x^2 \ln x\,dx
$$
I noticed that we can't evaluate it from $0$ to $2$, so I need to prove that it is divergent, but I can't do it in any way. Please help me.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ for typesetting math here. It helps in better presentation of the question.

Comment: When you do the improper integral and do IBP, you'll get a term looking like $x^3 \ln{x}$. Which goes to zero as x does. The issue with your integral is at infinity.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : It's MathJax, not $\LaTeX$.  The latter is not used only, or perhaps even primarilly, for mathematical notation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, To my knowledge, MathJax is the JavaScript library that _processes_ the $\LaTeX$ code we write and _displays_ it. What we write falls under $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : But it is highly misleading about the nature of $\LaTeX$ to say that this is $\LaTeX$.  When I run $\LaTeX$, I usually load one of more style files and packages before the \begin{document} statement, I use statements like \thispagestyle{empty} or \vspace{6pt} or \setcounter{enumi}{6}, or \label{basic lemma} and \ref{basic lemma}, or \cite{Smith} etc.  None of that has any application to MathJax, as far as I know.  One shouldn't lead those unfamiliar with $\LaTeX$ to think that familiarity with it can be acquired by mastering MathJax.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Ah, I didn't know that. +1 for the explanation. :D

Answer (score 1):

To prove the divergence of an improper integral, you need to show that the corresponding limit diverges.

Written out, this improper integral is defined as $\lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^2 x^2 \ln(x)\,dx$.  Evaluate the integral from $a$ to $2$ as a function of $a$, and then to show divergence you see that this function diverges as $a$ approaches 0 from the right.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \int(\ln x)\Big( x^2 \, dx\Big) = \int u\,dv=uv - \int v\,du = \frac{x^3}3\ln x - \int \frac{x^3} 3\cdot\frac 1 x \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{x^3}3\ln x - \frac 1 3 \int x^2 \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{x^3}3\ln x - \frac{x^3} 9 + C.
\end{align}

As $x\downarrow0$, the limit of the first term can be found by L'Hopital's rule applied to $\dfrac{\ln x}{1/x^3}$, and it is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\lim_{x\to0}x^n\ln x=0$, for $n>0$, so this isn't really an improper integral.

> $\displaystyle\int x^2\ln x\,dx=\frac{x^3}{3}\ln x-\int\frac{x^2}{3}\,dx$

Comment: (I think maybe you want to use $n=2$, and a right-hand limit as $x\to0$.)

Comment: @user84413 Yes, but it's a hint. It's not necessary to use the limit from the right, because the domain of the function is $x>0$; but it's just convention.

Comment: (I meant using $n=2$ in the hidden part of the answer.)

Comment: @user84413 Oh! You're right!

Answer (score 0):

Your integral is improper because $\log x$ is not defined at $x = 0$. To deal with this, we will check if we can integrate over the interval $[\epsilon, 2]$ for all (small) $\epsilon > 0$. That is, we are want to determine whether
$$
I = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_\epsilon ^2 x^2\log x\,dx
$$
is finite.

Integrating by parts,
$$
I = \lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} \frac{1}{3} x^3\log x \Big|_\epsilon^2 - \int_{\epsilon}^2 \frac{x^2}{3}\,dx.
$$

It's clear that last integral is finite so we need only check that 
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} x^3\log x
$$
exists and is finite.